# Overload constructor for the purpose of unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection

Kind of new to dependency injection and unit testing.

The why part:

Have some dlls:

- MyApp.Services.Common.dll
- MyApp.Services.ProductA.dll -> has ISomeDependency and its implementations
- MyApp.Services.ProductB.dll -> has IOtherDependency and its implementations
- MyApp.Presentation.WindowsService.dll

WindowsService only references Common.dll to keep testing, versioning, and deployment easier.

The problem is that any dependencies in ProductA and B.dll cannot be sent from WindowsService to Common dll because it would require an assembly reference in WindowsService to ProductA and B (do not want)

So, the unit test cannot isolate the dependencies when calling code in Common.dll.

Therefore, in order to isolate the dependencies, the code has an overloaded constructor that exposes the dependencies for testing only.

Is this okay?

See example below:

Unit test will mock the dependencies and call overloaded constructor, but real code calls default constructor

```
public class ClassUnderTest
{
  private ISomeDependency a;
  private IOtherDependency b;

  // constructor called by code
  public ClassUnderTest()
  {
     this.a = new SomeDependency();
     this.b = new OtherDependency();
  }
  public ClassUnderTest(ISomeDependency a, IOtherDependency b)
  {
    this.a = a;  
    this.b = b;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned that you can use constructor chaining.

```
public class ClassUnderTest
{
  readonly ISomeDependency a;
  readonly IOtherDependency b;

  public ClassUnderTest() : this(new SomeDependency(), new OtherDependency())
  {
  }

  public ClassUnderTest(ISomeDependency a, IOtherDependency b)
  {
     this.a = a;
     this.b = b;
  }
}
```

Although I fundamentally agree with everyone who said that an IOC container is the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of directly instantiating your concrete classes I would recommend that you let the IOC container inject the dependencies. If you do that, you can use the second constructor in both cases (constructor injection). Another alternative is to define public properties on your class and do property injection.

However, if you are not using an IOC container, and instead do "manual dependency injection" I see nothing wrong with the current pattern. It's ok to create "hooks" in your code for easier testing.

Answer (score 1):

With Dependency Injection, ultimately something has to inject the dependencies. I prefer to use a Dependency Injection Container for this purpose. Here's the catch: the object that does the composing needs to have assembly references to all of the actual objects.

There's a couple of ways to do this:

- place the DI Container's configuration code in Common.dll, and the test project needs to refer to common to compose objects (common.dll has some test scaffolding config code)
- test project has references to ProductA.dll and ProductB.dll, and has a DI Container configuration to assemble objects for testing that's separate from Common.dll

The real issue is your constructor. To test properly, you need to have test code and production code use the same constructor. That's why a Dependency Injection container exists: to handle the details of which objects get created for each Interface reference.

Answer (score 0):

> but real code calls default constructor

In this case, your test tells you nothing useful to help you figure out why the "real" code is blowing up in production, because you didn't actually test the default constructor.

Whilst I would agree with the other answers and urge you to go with an IoC container, if you *really* want to keep the pattern you currently have then at least expose the dependencies created inside the default `ctor` as public properties so that you can test them:

```
public class ClassUnderTest
{
  readonly ISomeDependency a;
  readonly IOtherDependency b;

  public ISomeDependency A{Get{return a;}}
  public ISomeDependency B{Get{return b;}}

  // constructor called by code
  public ClassUnderTest()
  {
     this.a = new SomeDependency();
     this.b = new OtherDependency();
  }
}

[TestMethod]
public void DefaultCTOR_CreatesDependencies()
{
    var sut = new ClassUnderTest();
    Assert.IsNotNull(sut.A,"sut didn't create SomeDependency A");
    Assert.IsNotNull(sut.B,"sut didn't create OtherDependency B");
}
```

Also re the dependency references.

If you moved `ISomeDependency` and `IOtherDependency` into their own assembly (**not** the implementations) then you will be able to reference this dll from both `ProductA` and `ProductB` assemblies as well as from your `Common`

- This provides you with loose coupling because your inter-assembly is all by interface only.
- You will suddenly find that DI becomes much clearer (and easier) in terms of where to put the injector
- All you have to do is make another project that references *everything* and it can resolve requests for `ISomeDependency` into concrete objects, and give those objects to `Common`, `ProductA` and `ProductB` *purely by interface*, and they'll be none the wiser :)